# use settimeout to prevent "Stop running this script" in jquery

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I have a long for loop to validate textboxes one row at a time in a table(over 1000 rows): i keep getting the "stop running this script" error. Many websites mentioned setTimeout() function. But i still cant get it to work. Here is my code:

```
var numRows = $("#tablex").attr('rows').length;
var errorMsg="";
for (var tbRow = 1; tbRow < numRows - 1; tbRow++) {
        var aRecord = $("#tablex tr:eq(" + tbRow + ") td:eq(1)").attr("innerText");
        var curECD = $("#tablex tr:eq(" + tbRow + ") td:eq(7)").find(':text').val().trim();

        if (curECD != "" && isDate(curECD) == false)
            errorMsg += "Date for " + aRecord + " is invalid<br/>";
 }
```

can anyone help? thanks!!!

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but I gotta' ask: why do you have over 1000 text inputs in one form?

Answer (score 0):

I made this [this little example](http://jsfiddle.net/qaqjb/5/) to help you with enumerating a list in chunks with a `setTimeout`.

```
function enumerate(list, groupSize, callback, complete, debug){
    var iterations = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i+=groupSize, iterations++){
        (function (group, index, isLast){ // new context
            setTimeout(function(){
                for (var j=0; j < group.length;j++){
                    debug && console.log(group[j]);
                    callback.call(group[j], (index+j+1));
                }
                isLast && complete.call();
            }, 1);
        })(list.slice(i, i+groupSize), i, (list.length < i+groupSize)); 
    }
    debug && console.log('iterations: ' + iterations);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var trs = $('#tablex tr'),
    errorMsg = '',
    onItem = function(){
        var aRecord = $("td:eq(1)", this).attr("innerText");
        var curECD = $("td:eq(7)", this).find(':text').val().trim();

        if (curECD != "" && isDate(curECD) == false)
           errorMsg += "Date for " + aRecord + " is invalid<br/>"; 
    },
    complete = function(){
        console.log(errorMsg);
    };

enumerate(trs, 5, onItem, complete);
```

Comment: @user629565 - here is how I would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first suggested  above solution is better, but you could also do it recursively like this I think. Depends what your requirements are:

```
var errorMsg="";    

function validateRow(row, callback){
    if(row.size() == 0){
        callback();
    }

    var aRecord = $("td:eq(1)", row).attr("innerText");
    var curECD = $("td:eq(7)", row).find(':text').val().trim();

    if (curECD != "" && isDate(curECD) == false)
       errorMsg += "Date for " + aRecord + " is invalid<br/>"; 

    setTimeout(function(){
        validateRow(row.next(), callback);
    }, 25);
}

validateRow($("#tablex tr:first"), function(){
     alert("finished validating");   
});
```

This will call validateRow and pass in the first row. ValidateRow will than call itself on a setTimeout and pass in the next row. When it reaches the end it will call a callback function that you supply.

Comment: It only loop through the first row, why? to answer your question: because the requirment changed, it was for 25-50 records first.